# "Array to string conversion" error when updating fields to livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8xRh.png)I want to edit a row as a fullpage.

The data is bound, but the fields give an "Array to string conversion" error when they are updated (when I type in the fields).

It does not give an error when I manually write the parameter in the query and do not use the route parameter. But I use route (according to the following code) gives the image error:

```
Route::get('Barnames/Edit/{Bar}', EditBar::class)-;
```

I delete this parameter {Bar. I can update the fields without error (I type inside the fields).

This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Barnames;
use Livewire\Component;
class EditBarname extends Component
{


    public $Barname = [];


    public function mount()
    {
   
        $this->Barname =['maghsad'=>"testi"];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.barnames.testi')
            ->extends('layouts.app')
            ->section('content');
    }
}
```

view:

```
<div>
    <input wire:model='Barname.maghsad' type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

route :

```
Route::get('Bar/Edit/{Bar?}', EditBar::class)->name('EditBar')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understood the problem
If a word is selected in the route parameter ({Bar}) that exists in the component variables, it gives this error

Comment: Also, parameters in routes should not start with capital letters

Comment: @xformer i had the same problem, please answer your question and mark it as solved